# Mongoose - Delete selected element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Displaying data from mongoose in table. How to make Delete Button to work properly, to delete selected element from table

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-12 column list-group">
        {% for note in notes %}
        <div class="list-group-item">
            <div>Note from <em><strong>{{ note.memberName }}</strong></em> on: {{ note.createdOn.toDateString() }}``
                 - for project: <strong>{{ note.project }}</strong></div>
            <div><strong>Work yesterday:</strong> {{ note.workYesterday }}</div>
            <div><strong>Work today:</strong> {{ note.workToday }}</div>
            <div><strong>Impediment:</strong> {{ note.impediment }}</div>

            <form action="/delete" method="post">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">DELETE</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

index.js

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
 var id = req.body.id;
 Standup.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
 res.redirect('/');
});
```

[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jQnS.png)

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear but based on the code you provided, it does not seem like you're sending the Id of the note you want to delete to your server. One way you can do it is by adding a hidden form field with the value of the id note. For example your form could look something like this (assuming that you have access to note.id on the client side:

```
<form action="/delete" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ note.id }}">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">DELETE</button>
</form>
```

This way when you submit the form, you'll send the value of that note's id in the request body of your server and be able to access it from your `req.body`.

As other answers have mentioned, you should also provide a callback as a second argument to `findByIdAndRemove` since it is asynchronous. For example:

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    Standup.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err, deletedStandUp) {
       // handle any potential errors here
       res.redirect('/');        
     });
});
```

This way, your redirect won't happen until the delete has completed or an error is thrown. So when your `'/'` route renders, it will have up to date data.

Finally, I'd also recommend making your route more RESTful and making the method `DELETE` and have the route name relate to the resource that that controller method handles (in this case it would be `/note`. But for this is not necessary to fix your your current issue.

Comment: Thanks @Shaka, your replay was just what I needed.
This trick with hidden field is great !

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```
findByIdAndRemove(id,function(){
      res.redirect('/');
 });
```

That way, it only redirects to the webpage after the item is removed. The second argument is the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the callback of the deletion request:

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    Standup.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err, deletedStandUp) {
       if(err){
         res.status(500);
       }
       res.redirect('/');        
     });
});
```

You could also add status code 404 if the requested object did not found but it doesn't seem necessary as this is a delete. so its actually depends on you requirements:

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    Standup.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err, deletedStandUp) {
       if(err){
         res.status(500);
       } else if(!deletedStandup){
         res.status(404);
       }
       res.redirect('/');        
     });
});
```

in another manner delete request are better use with delete instead of post:

```
router.delete(function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.startup_id
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dromat on very clear explanation, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the id of the message back as a URL parameter or part of your form(looks like your using the body, so it should be an input).

you can grab the id by using note._id(i believe this is auto built into mongoose).